# Sed to change a birth date using a regular expression

Tags: sed

I'm interested in changing a birth date in a text file to a different date of 11/14/46.  I want to do this without having to know the previous birth date and instead be able to search generically.  I know the person's name that the birth date is associated with, so I can use that to make the substitution

I've tried this:

```
sed "s/^PersonsName\/[1-12]\/[0-31]\/[0-99]/11\/14\/46/g" txt.file
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not sure how to proceed

---

The suggested answers below haven't worked for me.  I'm going to give some example data and see if this helps to clarify.

```
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:3/19/35:22350
```

Let's pretend I'm trying to change Popeye's birth date (which is at the end), but I want to search without having to know his current one.  I know using a regular expression is key here, but so far the examples I've seen haven't worked.  Maybe providing the above example data will help

[Expected Output]

```
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:11/14/46:22350
```

All I'm interested in changing is the birth date at the end to `11/14/46`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, please see the updates

Comment: did all the lines are in the exact format you specified?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I didn't really understand that sentence.  But what you see above as examples are the format I want.  And all the lines are in the same format as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below sed command,

```
$ sed '/^Popeye Sailor:/s/:[^:]*\(:[^:\/]*\)$/:11\/14\/46\1/' file
Popeye Sailor:156-454-3322:945 Bluto Street, Anywhere, USA 29358:11/14/46:22350
```

It changes the date only on the lines which starts with `Popeye Sailor:`

Comment: that worked perfectly!  Thank you for all your help today, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

`[1-12]\/[0-31]` and `[0-99]` do not mean 1 to 12, 0 to 31 and 0 to 99.

- `[1-12]` means a range of characters starting from 1 till 1, and a 2. In essence: `[12]`. (Compare with `[0-1a]`.)
- `[0-31]`  means a range of characters starting from 0 till 3, and a 1: `[0123]`.

Similarly for `[0-99]`. Expressing a range of numbers with regular expressions isn't easy.

If the numbers don't use double digits (`01/06/33`), you'll have to do something like:
`[0-9]{1,2}` for day and month, and `[0-9]{2}` for the year, or the regex will quickly grow unwieldy. This, of course, risks the selection of something like `99/99/99`.

For an example:

```
$ sed "s/^\(muru\/\)[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}/\111\/14\/46/g" <<<'muru/1/4/85'
muru/11/14/46
$ sed "s/^\(muru\/\)[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}/\111\/14\/46/g" <<<'muru/10/4/85'
muru/11/14/46
$ sed "s/^\(muru\/\)[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}/\111\/14\/46/g" <<<'muru/10/28/85'
muru/11/14/46
```

I assume you want to retain the name, so I used [backreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574302/using-backreferences-regex-in-sed) to refer to it in the substitution (the `\1`).

Comment: I think I'm following you.  Could you please provide an explicit example so that I can understand you fully?

Comment: @Justin is the update helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are [tricky](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html), but simplifying to a similar extent to your attempt…

```
sed -r 's,^PersonsName1?[0-9]/[1-3]?[0-9]/[0-9]{2},11/14/46,' txt.file
```

### Explanation

- Use `-r` for extended regular expressions. This allows (for example) `?`.
- Generally, I prefer single quotes `'` rather than double `"`, so there's no shell expansion.
- Instead of using `/` as `sed` delimiters, you can use whatever you want. Here I've used `,`, so that we don't need to escape literal `/`s.
- `1?[0-9]` match an optional `1` and required 0-9, for the month.
- `[1-3]?[0-9]` match and optional 1-3, and a required 0-9 for the day.
- `[0-9]{2}` match two digits for the year.
- N.B. that this will potentially have some false matches. e.g. `0/0/00` and `19/39/99` will match, but you can tweak the regex more if you like. See the link above for more information.

### More comments

Note that this matches something like `PersonsName11/11/11`, and replaces the whole thing, similar to what your attempt tried to do. If you want to only replace the date, you can use the following instead.

```
sed -r 's,^(PersonsName)1?[0-9]/[1-3]?[0-9]/[0-9]{2},\111/14/46,' txt.file
```

Here, we capture `PersonsName`, using parens. Then we can refer to it again in the replace section with `\1`.